# Writing into .long in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att, mov

I have issue with writing into allocated memory. Here's the code.

```
total: .long 1       # my memory

movl total, %eax     # I believe I'm copying address of total into eax
movl $53, %esi       # set some value in esi
movl (%esi), %eax    # and put this value into total
```

Why its not working? It gives : "Naruszenie ochrony pamięci" (core dumped) this is in Polish and means something like memory access violation.

Comment: The parenthesis are around the wrong thing.

Comment: Sounds like assembly courses at the universities have begun once again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in AT&T syntax, to store the address of a label into a register, instead of

```
movl total, %eax
```

which disassembles in Intel syntax as:

```
8b042500000000   mov eax, [0x0]
```

you need to use:

```
movl $total, %eax
```

which disassembles as something like this:

```
b800000000       mov eax, 0x0
```

In this sense when using AT&T syntax one has to be very careful to avoid bugs.

Then, if you fix the above problem, you still need to fix the parentheses of the last instruction, as mentioned by Seva and harold. It should be like this:

```
movl %esi, (%eax)
```

The code causes a segmentation fault because it accesses memory regions you don't have access to. In protected mode you can't access whatever memory address  you wish, you need to have read/write/execute rights for that memory region.

Comment: So, is there other way to store some data in memory? I cant change total?

Comment: You can do some of the following to store some data in memory: 1. reserve memory in the `data` section of your code, or 2. use stack for local variables, or 3. request a memory block from your OS (eg. with `malloc`).

Comment: @Kmaczek But anyway it assembles with `gas` without any warnings :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace with

```
movl %esi, (%eax)
```